# Order of profinite groups

Tags: group-theory

So as we know, if $G$ is a profinite group, then the order of $G$ is defined to be
$|G| = \textrm{lcm}(\{G/N\})$
where $N$ runs over all normal subgroups of finite index of $G$. [(see here)](http://planetmath.org/OrderOfAProfiniteGroup.html)

> Question : Let $K$ be a finite group and $G=K^\alpha$ the direct product of copies of $K$ where $\alpha$ is a cardinal number. What should the order of $\widehat{G}$ be?

I think it should be $|K|^{2^\alpha}$ but then I do not know how to figure out.

Comment: I suppose you mean $$\varprojlim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$$?

Comment: Also, the example is not so directly related to the question: $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ is not a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. Or is it so? If so, forgive my ignorance and inform me; if not so, please change the question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: @Awllower : Thanks, I edited.

Comment: As a [supernatural number](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Supernatural_number), the order is $\prod_{p\mid\#K}p^\infty$.

Comment: Instead of $|K|^{2^\alpha}$, it's probably $|K|^\alpha$, right? That makes more sense when $|K|$ is finite or $\alpha=1$.